# Poloniex C# API - get trades

Tags: c#, ethereum, poloniex

I am using the Poloniex C# API available here: [Poloniex C#](https://github.com/Jojatekok/PoloniexApi.Net).

I have connected to my Poloniex account via the public/private key combination

```
private PoloniexClient client = new PoloniexClient(Properties.Resources.PublicKey, Properties.Resources.PrivateKey);
```

and I have a method for getting trades info

```
public async void GetTrades(string curr1, string curr2)
{
   CurrencyPair cp = new CurrencyPair(curr1, curr2);
   var trades = await client.Markets.GetTradesAsync(cp);
   foreach (var x in trades)
       Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

which uses the API's `GetTradesAsync()` method, but the output I get is

> Jojatekok.PoloniexAPI.MarketTools.Trade
>
> Jojatekok.PoloniexAPI.MarketTools.Trade
>
> Jojatekok.PoloniexAPI.MarketTools.Trade
>
> ...

This is the first time I'm using Poloniex (and anything related to crypto-currencies, really) so I'm not sure what the actual result should look like, but I'm sure I was actually supposed to get something more meaningful. I'd appreciate any help or advice.

Comment: Is this push API ? or do you need to make calls in regular intervals to get the data ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Outputting the Trade will just show you the type. You want to output whatever properties you're interested in, e.g.

```
foreach (var x in trades)
   Console.WriteLine(x.AmountBase + " " + x.AmountQuote + " "+x.PricePerCoin);
```